# Use globalDependencies (Typescript tsd files) from Angular2

Tags: typescript, angular

I'm trying to use typescript tsd's from DefinitelyTyped in an Angular2 project (RC.0), but global dependencies doesn't seem to load properly:

```
typings install --save dt~hellojs --global --save
npm install --save hellojs
```

I've this configurations:

typings.json:

```
"globalDependencies": {
  "hellojs": "registry:dt/hellojs#0.2.3+20160423145325"
}
```

angular.cli.build.js:

```
module.exports = function(defaults) {
  return new Angular2App(defaults, {
    vendorNpmFiles: [
      'systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
      'systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
      'zone.js/dist/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      'es6-shim/es6-shim.js',
      'reflect-metadata/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      'rxjs/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      '@angular/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      'angular2-moment/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      'moment/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      'hellojs/**/*.+(js|js.map)'
    ]
  });
};
```

system-config.ts

```
/** Map relative paths to URLs. */
const map: any = {
  'moment': 'vendor/moment',
  'angular2-moment': 'vendor/angular2-moment',
  'hellojs': 'vendor/hellojs/dist'
};

/** User packages configuration. */
const packages: any = {
  'moment': { main: 'moment.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
  'angular2-moment': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
  'hellojs': { main: 'hello.all.js' }
};
```

but, if I use the new dependency from an angular module, like this:

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {FormBuilder, ControlGroup} from "@angular/common";
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Router} from "@angular/router";
import {LoginResourceService} from "../shared/services/resources/login-resource.service";
import {AuthService} from "../shared/services/auth.service";
import {AppRoutes} from "../app-routes";

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.component.html',
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  providers: [LoginResourceService],
  styleUrls: ['login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent {

  userForm:ControlGroup;
  errorMessage:string;

  constructor(formBuilder:FormBuilder, private _loginResource:LoginResourceService, public router:Router,
              private _auth:AuthService) {
    this.userForm = this.buildLoginForm(formBuilder);
  }
  // ...
  example() {
    hello.init({});
  }

}
```

I'm getting compiler errors:

```
Error: Typescript found the following errors:
  /Users/fer2d2/dev/personal/web-projects/front-joinfinity/tmp/broccoli_type_script_compiler-input_base_path-xa8whw1k.tmp/0/src/app/+login/login.component.ts (62, 5): Cannot find name 'hello'.
```

If I try to import the module with `import * as hello from "hellojs"` or `import hello = require("hellojs")` the fail persists.

How can I use a globalDependency from Angular2?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

With:
`import {hello} from "hellojs"` or
`import hello from "hellojs"` or
`import hello = require("hellojs")`

I'm getting this error:

```
Error: Typescript found the following errors: /Users/fer2d2/dev/personal/web-projects/front-joinfinity/tmp/broccoli_type_scrip‌​t_compiler-input_base_path-tKuuBwei.tmp/0/src/app/+login/login.component.ts (7, 21): Cannot find module 'hellojs'.
```

It seems like Typescript or systemjs aren't loading globalDependencies tsd's propely.

Comment: try: `import {hello} from "hellojs"`

Comment: and: `import hello from "hellojs"`

Comment: What is the error for `import hello = require("hellojs")`?

Comment: Hi @2426021684. With: `import {hello} from "hellojs"` and `import hello from "hellojs"` and `import hello = require("hellojs")` i'm getting this error: `Error: Typescript found the following errors:
  /Users/fer2d2/dev/personal/web-projects/front-joinfinity/tmp/broccoli_type_script_compiler-input_base_path-tKuuBwei.tmp/0/src/app/+login/login.component.ts (7, 21): Cannot find module 'hellojs'.`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved my problem:

In Angular2, using and using Angular-CLI, you have a file called typings.d.ts which imports all the typings installed via `typings install`. In this file you can see the following import line:

```
/// <reference path="../typings/browser.d.ts" />
```

The browser.d.ts just contains the typings for Angular2 between some other typings. If you want to use globalDependencies, `typings` will add them to the file typings/index.d.ts. So, in your typings.d.ts, you must add the following line:

```
/// <reference path="../typings/browser.d.ts" />
```

My problem seems to be related with the latest update of typings, where 'ambient' was replaced with 'global' as prefix for this dependencies.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/typings#updating-from-0x-to-10